# Specified port 3306 is already in use when installing MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, backend

I had used MySQL earlier and then later uninstalled it. But now when I try to re-install, it says that "the specified port 3306 is already in use". Is there any way to solve this problem?

I tried this method to solve but it didn't help

Another instance is already running:

> This error occurs when MySql has been installed by you in command
> line (cmd) before installing XAMPP server.

- Open cmd and run as administrator
- So, type this in command-line (cmd ) = “sc delete mysql”
- It will show you that the running instance has deleted successfully.

Answer (score 7):

1. In the search, Go to Run
2. Type "services.msc"
3. Search "MySQL" in running status and "stop" it.
4. Refresh the server and now install.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

If you are *linux* user,

Find the task that use port 3306 with command

```
lsof -i TCP:3306
```

Find the PID of the task and kill it with command

```
kill -9 PID_NUMBER
```

Answer (score 1):

On windows Ctrl + shift + delete to open task manager. Go-to services and scroll down to MySQl80, right click on it and select stop. Restart your xampp and start MySQL.

Comment: There is no option for Services....

Answer (score 0):

i've also encountered the same error. But what I did was a rookie mistake. I had my XAMPP opened and running mySQL on XAMPP while I am installing mySQL. So all I did was to stop mySQL on XAMPP and the port error is gone!

Answer (score -1):

If you are on a Windows machine, I suggest you to follow the steps mentioned below to uninstall MySQL from the device.

- **Step 1**

Uninstall MySQL from Control Panel. To do so,

Go to Control Panel > Programs and Features > Select MySQL > Click on Uninstall.

After you have uninstalled MySQL through Add/Remove programs, you now need to remove the existing database information which includes your actual data.  If you need any of that data, be sure to back it up. Next you can delete the data directory.

- **Step 2**

Run Command Prompt as `Administrator` and execute the following command to stop and remove MySQL service.

Net stop MySQL

Sc delete MySQL

- **Step 3**

Click on Start, type in Show hidden files and folders.

Select the View tab and select Show hidden files and folders.

Now explore the following locations and delete following folders.

1. C:\Program Files\MySQL
2. C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL
3. C:\ProgramData\MySQL

And if exists, delete the folder from the location.

- C:\Users[Your-User-Name]\AppData\Roaming\MySQL

Restart your device and check the status.

*source:* [Microsoft](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-windows_programs/how-to-completely-uninstall-mysql/e90e1344-7b90-4319-8b2f-77b271ae66ed)